# Docker - docker-compose - postgres image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using the postgres:latest image, and creating backups using the following command

```
pg_dump postgres -U postgres > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/backups/redmine-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M).sql
```

and it's running periodically using crontab

```
*/30 * * * * /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/backup.sh
```

However, on occasion I might need to run

```
docker-compose down/up
```

for whatever reason

**The problem**
I always need to manually run `/etc/init.d/cron start` whenever I restart the container. This is a bit of a problem because it's difficult to remember to do, and if I (or anyone else) forgets this, backups wont be made

According to the documentation, scripts ending with `*.sql` and `*.sh` inside the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` are run on container startup (and they do)
However, if I put `/etc/init.d/cron start` inside a executable `.sh` file, the other commands inside that file are executed and I've verified that. But the cron service does not start, probably because the `/etc/init.d/cron start` inside the executable file does not execute successfully

I would appreciate any suggestion for a solution

Comment: Can you provide your `dockerfile` or atleast let us know the base image you used (ubuntu/centos) ?

Comment: @mchawre I used postgres:latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @Jite's answer, you could run `pg_dump` remotely in a different container using the `--host` [option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

This [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/kalumkalac/postgresql-client), for example, provides a minimal environment with `psql` client and dump/restore utilities

Comment: I like this. I want the entire functionality to be illustrated in the docker-compose file

Answer (score 2):

You will want to keep your docker containers as independent of other services as possible, I would recommend that you instead of running the cronjob in the container do it on the host, that way it will run even if the container is restarted (weather automatically or manually).

If you really really feel the need for it, I would build a new image with the postgres image as base, and add the cron right from there, that way it is in the container already from start, without any extra scripts needed. Or even create another image just to invoke the cronjob and connect via the docker network.

Comment: I want the the entire functionality of the container for administration to be contained  to only having to execute `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose down`, so if I go on vacation, quit or die, if for some reason the application is moved to another VM, the backups will still be made as long is the container is started and not subject to other admins reading the documentation

Comment: Then I would recommend adding a cron-job container to run parallel with your other in the compose file.

Comment: Thank you, I will